# How to fetch content from other websites in jsp and java ???

Tags: java, jsp

I am a beginner in java programming . i want to establish as a java programmer in web based application . Now at begning i want to develop cms and also want to fetch data from other website so i am looking for the effective code.
thank you

Comment: if you right click on the page, and click view source, you can see the full HTML code for the webpage.

Comment: What _type_ of data you are trying to fetch?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Example:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputstreamReader(con.openStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
}
```

This should print out the source code of Stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSTL [`<c:import />`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0318/) to importing content.